# Ghostscript 9.14 - Create PDFA from PS

Tags: ghostscript

I have a requirement of creating PDFA Document from PS in my LINUX environment.

I am using the following command line to generate the same:
gs -q -dPDFA=2 -sColorConversionStrategy=/RGB  -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=pdfA_New.pdf /project/mgos/9.14/lib/PDFA_def.ps Sample.ps

I am able to create PDFA Document however the Standards show the following:
1. Standard:PDF/A-2B . This should be 2U for me.

2. Also the Output Intent data is missing.

Let me know if I am missing anything.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript doesn't support PDF/A-2U at all, just PDF/A-2b. I really really don't recommend use of PDFSETTINGS if you plan to request PDF/A output.

And you should upgrade to Ghostscript 9.15 as well.